# How do i create a UITextView in main UIView from a UIButton Within UIPopover?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uitextview, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to create a `UITextView` in my Main `UIViewController` when a `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` happens with my UIButton which is in a `UIPopoverController`.
I tried to use a delegate protocol to allow my button to be referenced within the Main viewcontroller.m but I don't think I have been doing it right. I will also mention I've created the `UIButton` and `UITextField` programmatically in a `UIView` subclass for the `UIPopover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view controller that you display in the `UIPopoverController` should look something like this:

```
@interface MyViewControllerForPopover : UIViewController
    @property (weak) UIViewController *viewControllerInWhichCreateTheTextField;
    ...
@end
```

Meaning that you could keep a weak reference to the view controller in which you want to add the text field. The button you generated in this `MyViewControllerForPopover` could do something like:

```
- (void)createTextViewInConnectedViewController:(id)sender {
    UITextField *myTextField = ...;
    [self.viewControllerInWhichCreateTheTextView.view addSubview:myTextField];
}
```

The key concept is that you want to have a weak reference (to avoid retain cycle) to the view controller you wish to alter. Even better if that view controller has a method to actually add the text field itself. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the Reply I will give your method a go!